# MICE package in R 10x slower with new R

Tags: r, missing-data, imputation, r-mice, r-environment

I recently updated my `R` (from 4.0 to 4.2) and now `mice()` runs **much** slower on the same data. Has this happened to anyone else ?

Maybe my `.Renviron` got reset and something like the `R_MAX_VSIZE` needs to change ? It doesn't seem to help `mice()`.

Thank you !

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Monterey 12.3.1

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] mice_3.14.0     bigrquery_1.4.0 forcats_0.5.1   stringr_1.4.0   dplyr_1.0.9    
 [6] purrr_0.3.4     readr_2.1.2     tidyr_1.2.0     tibble_3.1.7    ggplot2_3.3.6  
[11] tidyverse_1.3.1 sqldf_0.4-11    RSQLite_2.2.14  gsubfn_0.7      proto_1.0.0    
[16] mgcv_1.8-40     nlme_3.1-157    civis_3.0.0    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] httr_1.4.3        bit64_4.0.5       jsonlite_1.8.0    splines_4.2.0     modelr_0.1.8     
 [6] assertthat_0.2.1  blob_1.2.3        cellranger_1.1.0  progress_1.2.2    globals_0.15.0   
[11] pillar_1.7.0      backports_1.4.1   lattice_0.20-45   glue_1.6.2        chron_2.3-56     
[16] digest_0.6.29     rvest_1.0.2       colorspace_2.0-3  Matrix_1.4-1      pkgconfig_2.0.3  
[21] broom_0.8.0       listenv_0.8.0     haven_2.5.0       scales_1.2.0      tzdb_0.3.0       
[26] generics_0.1.2    ellipsis_0.3.2    cachem_1.0.6      withr_2.5.0       cli_3.3.0        
[31] magrittr_2.0.3    crayon_1.5.1      readxl_1.4.0      memoise_2.0.1     fs_1.5.2         
[36] future_1.25.0     fansi_1.0.3       parallelly_1.31.1 xml2_1.3.3        prettyunits_1.1.1
[41] tools_4.2.0       hms_1.1.1         gargle_1.2.0      lifecycle_1.0.1   munsell_0.5.0    
[46] reprex_2.0.1      compiler_4.2.0    rlang_1.0.2       grid_4.2.0        rstudioapi_0.13  
[51] arrow_8.0.0       gtable_0.3.0      codetools_0.2-18  DBI_1.1.2         curl_4.3.2       
[56] brutils_0.1.0     R6_2.5.1          lubridate_1.8.0   fastmap_1.1.0     bit_4.0.4        
[61] utf8_1.2.2        stringi_1.7.6     parallel_4.2.0    Rcpp_1.0.8.3      vctrs_0.4.1      
[66] dbplyr_2.1.1      tidyselect_1.1.2
```

Sadly I don't have `sessionInfo()` for my previous version of `R`.

Comment: Can you provide the results of `sessionInfo()`? Are you able to provide that for the older version of R as well if that's still around? It would be good to know the OS and matrix libraries that are being used as well as the exact version of MICE that's being used in the two different setups. It would also be nice to have some sort of [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that we could run to test if we see the same thing as well.

Comment: added, @MrFlick ! sorry I don't have the old `sessionInfo()` though...